# Is it necessary to use '1>' while redirecting standard output in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command

Is it necessary to use `1>` while redirecting standard output stream in Linux terminal?
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuDmS.png)..

This command is also working without using 1 while redirecting stdout in Linux. So my question is what is the difference between using and not using 1 while redirecting Standard Output in Linux terminal?

I tried with and without using 1 while redirecting Standard output stream in Linux. I got what I want all the time. But I need to know the difference between using and not using 1 while redirecting Standard output stream in Linux terminal.

Comment: I added some tags; this is fundamentally a question about the syntax of your shell, which on Linux is typically Bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary; the number is optional because it defaults to `1` when you omit it.

The general syntax is *n*`>` where *n* is the number of an open file descriptor. You can open new file descriptors e.g. with `exec` (so `exec 3>&1` duplicates file descriptor 1 to file descriptor 3) or you can inherit open file descriptors from a parent process.

By default, the shell gives you standard input on file descriptor 0, standard output on 1, and standard error on 2, all connected to your terminal.